# White Block on the right side (outside html)

Tags: html, css

I have the problem, that a white block appears outside the html on my page.
There is no content, firebug reports it to be outside the html tag.

I guess the problem should be an image, which is too wide or a padding exceeding the 100%, but I couldn't find anything so far. Maybe anybody has an idea.

The page i am referring to is: [**www.sailbook.org**](https://www.sailbook.org/app/registration/register.mvc)

**EDIT:**
I found out, it has to be an Javascript issue, since disabling Java Script removes the error. The problem is: without Javascript the site works only half as good. And the have a lot of scripts implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can tell you that its due to relative positioning, because when you use the top/left/bottom/right values the [space the element originally occupied](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning) is still considered, and remains in the document flow.

The problem is specifically `#controlmenu {position: relative; left: 50%;}` if you remove the left value you'll notice the white-space disappear .. though I'm not sure how that would affect your layout ..

Comment: Thanks, I just found it myself the exact same minute.
But you are right, without it, the menu does not position, where I want it to be. I want it to be vertically centered, like it is.